# Empty relations when serializing with JMSSerializer

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I am having troubles while writing a controller-action inside a Symfony project, that should return data (in this particular case orders of a web-shop). Yeah ... It's a kind of a REST-API. That route just get's called from some JavaScript. And the data has to be visualized on the client-side.

The Problem:

I cannot find out, why the serialization of related entities results in empty objects. In this example it is the user of an order, which is empty.

This is a sample output:

```
orders: [
  {
    id: 2,
    created: '2016-05-04T11:40:27+00:00',
    user: {},
  }
]
```

When I do something like

```
$orders = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Order')
  ->findAllCompleted();

$serializationContext->setSerializeNull(true);
$serializationContext->setGroups(['statistics']);

$json = $serializer->serialize($orders, 'json', $serializationContext);
$response = new Response($json, $statusCode, [
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
]);

return $response;
```

... i get a nice JSON response from the server, but every related entity of each order, like let's say `user` is `{}` (empty).

Even if I dump the related entity before it gets serialized like so:

```
[...]
$myOrder = array_filter($orders, function($order) {
  if ($order->getId() == 2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

dump($myOrder[0]->getUser());
die();
```

... it results in an empty (unhydrated) entity.

But if I change this debugging code to:

```
$myOrder = array_filter($orders, function($order) {
  if ($order->getId() == 2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

dump($myOrder[0]->getUser()->getUsername());
die();
```

... I get a clear output (string) with the value of the username of that entity.

So I think the issue is about a non hydrated entity, and not the serializer or its wrong configuration.

How can I get the JMSSerializer to take care of the hydration of those related entities?

I didn't find any hint in the docs ...

BTW, this are the JMS entity configs of order and user.

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
  exclusion_policy: ALL
  properties:
    userMeta:
      expose: true
    address:
      expose: true
    username:
      expose: true
    email:
      expose: true
    isReseller:
      expose: true
    acceptPublicOrders:
      expose: true
    vatNumber:
      expose: true
    taxRate:
      expose: true


AppBundle\Entity\Order:
  exclusion_policy: NONE
  properties:
    id:
      groups: ['statistics']

    user:
      groups: ['statistics']

    configuration:
      groups: ['statistics']

    created:
      groups: ['statistics']

    invoiceItems:
      groups: ['statistics']
      exclude: true
```

Comment: Have you set a `exclusion_policy: all` on `User` ?

Comment: Yes. But I also have explicit `expose: true` directives. See my updated question with the relevant jms entity configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by doctrine lazy loading maybe you can try to change the fetch mode of the User association to EAGER in your Order entity

> @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cart", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")

By default i think it doesn't fetch the associations unless you call it  directly like you did here

> dump($myOrder[0]->getUser()->getUsername());

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-onetoone

Or this if you use DQL
14.7.6.6. Temporarily change fetch mode in DQL

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#temporarily-change-fetch-mode-in-dql

Edit : i was wrong
I made some tests everything worked fine with lazy loading or eager until i tried with groups, even if the fields are exposed you don't use the Default group so it only take the things with the 'statistics' group on it
Try to add the default group here

> $serializationContext->setGroups(['Default','statistics']);

Or add the statistics group on your user fields both worked for me

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. It has to do with lazy loading. Because I have controll about the fields that get serialized. If I set some `exclude: true` in the yml configuration or via annotation the `user` field doesnt exist at all in my API responne, which is fine. But that it's NULL, has to do with lazy loading. I am not sure if EAGER results in bad performance with thousands of orders. Isn't there another way? I don't know why, but in my other API endpoints there is no problem with serializing relations. They all get populated with their values ...

Comment: Ok i think i got it, i made some tests everything worked fine with lazy loading or eager until i tried with groups, even if the fields are exposed you don't use the Default group so it only take the things with the 'statistics' group on it
Try to add the default group here
$serializationContext->setGroups(['Default','statistics']);
Or add the statistics group on the user fields that you need 
Both worked for me

Comment: adding 'Default' Group is not an option because in this context it responses get until 30MB of json :-) But adding the statistics group to the metadata definition is the way to achieve it. Anyway it didn't work. Thats why I stripped out the JMSSerializerBundle of the whole project. Just doing some refactoring and so I can use the Symfony/Serializer Component, which does a fine job right now. I Just have to figure out how to implement the virtual property feature...